# How to make Select option first value not to redirect to any page?

Tags: html, redirect, hyperlink

I have a dropdown showing in the no results page.

This is what I am doing

```
<label for="chewie"></label>
 <select name="chewie" id="chewie" onchange="redirect()">
  <option > Select Option</option>
  <option value="www.item1.com">Item1</option>
  <option value="www.item1.com">Item1</option>
  <option value="www.item1.com">Item1</option>
  <option value="www.item1.com">Item1</option>
 </select>
```

If user select Item1, it redirects to item1 page. When he clicks on back button and selects 'Select Option' it should stay on the page where this dropdown is.

But now, when user selects 'Select Option' it goes to 404 page not found obviously.

I do not want 1st option  to redirect to any page. What value should I provide so that it doesn't redirect to any other page?

Comment: Could you maybe show us how `redirect()` works?

Comment: My redirect works this way -                                    function redirect()

{   //capture the selection

 var selected_index = document.redirectdropdown.chewie.selectedIndex;

 var redirect_url = document.redirectdropdown.chewie.options[selected_index].value;

 //redirect the user

 window.location=redirect_url;

 return false;

}

Comment: I was just wondering if there was a way to filter it in that function and to prevent it from trying to navigate away if `selectedIndex = 0`, for example.

Comment: I was initially exploring this. Not that I know of. But would be glad to hear if you find something.

Comment: I added an answer that uses Javascript to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use an anchor value like value="#"

Comment: If we disable, then the default value selected will not be 'select option'. It will be the next element in the dropdown. So, it wont make any sense to put 'Select option' at all when the default value is greyed out and not selected in any case.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `<option disabled>Select Option</option>` so the option can't be clicked.

Comment: By disabling 'select option' the default value selected will not be select option, but it will be the 2nd option. So this solution does not work.

Comment: you need to add `selected` after `disabled` and it will be first selected when page loads.

Comment: Derik, if i disable the field it greys out. If it is selected then it should be displayed in regular font style, not greyed.

Answer (score 0):

just remove the `urls` from the value attribute in the `option` tag

```
  <label for="chewie"></label>
  <select name="chewie" id="chewie" onchange="redirect()">
  <option> Select Option</option>
  <option>Item1</option>
  <option>Item2</option>
  <option>Item3</option>
  <option>Item4</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: This is not what I want. Each of these options except the 1st one should redirect to different urls.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to put something in the Javascript to prevent it from redirecting. Let's say the first option is always going to be a place-holder, so you want to ignore the action... you could check the selected index and only perform the action if the index is greater than zero.

```
function redirect() { 
  //capture the selection 
  var dropdown = document.getElementById("chewie");
  if(dropdown.selected_index > 0)
  { 
     //redirect the user 
     var redirect_url = dropdown.options[selected_index].value;
     window.location = redirect_url; 
  }

  return false;
}
```

Also, you might want to put `http://` in front of the URLs... in my browser they didn't redirect correctly without that.